# Batch move "%1" to location

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a script that function as a shortcut, lets i wanna send the input to My Pictures

```
@echo off

echo drop input

pause

move "%1" "C:\Users\%username%\Pictures"

pause
```

The problem seems to be that the %1 / input needs to be described in some way.
cause when i drop a image it says 
        The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: What is your question? Does the code you posted work? If not, in what way is it failing? Please [edit] your post and make it clear what problem you're asking us to help you solve.

Comment: Have you tried `echo "%1"`? What was the result? Echoing things is the basic way to debug batch files.

Comment: Something happend when i looped it and removed pause

Comment: some times i guess you have to push that 1 hour research a little more.. here the answer:

@echo off

:1

set /p var=%1

echo drop input

echo "%1"

echo %var%

move %var% "C:\Users\%username%\Pictures"
goto 1

regards x

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 

    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:loopParameters
    rem Variable to hold file name
    set "file="

    rem If a file has been dropped on batch file, retrieve if from parameters
    rem If no file dropped, ask for one
    if "%~1"=="" (
        set /p "file=Drop file here:"
    ) else (
        set "file=%~1"
    )

    rem Check if there is something to do. If not, the process has ended
    if not defined file goto endProcess
    if not exist "%file%" goto endProcess

    rem Do the work
    echo move "%file%" "C:\Users\%username%\Pictures"

    rem Determine if there is something more to process
    if not "%~1"=="" if not "%~2"=="" ( shift & goto :loopParameters )

:endProcess
    rem Wait to see output of commands
    echo.
    pause

    rem Clean and exit 
    endlocal
    exit /b
```

It will process files dropped into the batch file (without first starting batch file). If batch file is started without dropping any file on it , it will ask for one file to process.

If files are dropped into batch file, explorer generates the list of files to be processed as separate arguments to batch file. So first file will be in `%1`, second in `%2`, ... In this code, the file to be processed is retrieved from `%1`. Once the first file is processed, if there are more files to process, `shift` command is used to "shift" the argument list, so the content of `%2` will be in `%1`, `%3` will be in `%2`, ... That way, the next file to process will be again in `%1` in each iteration.

BUT there is a limit of 8191 characters in the length of a command line. As explorer passes the full list of selected files in the same command line, if there is a lot of files selected, the final part of the list will not be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You need the tilda in the command as shown below, as dropping quoted iems on it will fail if it doesn't have the tilda.

```
move "%~1" "C:\Users\%username%\Pictures"
```